# import a script from another folder with importlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a project file containing my main script. Furthermore I have a sub directory that contains my scripts I want to import at different times. This is what the path looks like. `\\projectPath\\data\\scripts\\` Then I have a `__init__.py` file and a script called `Snake.py` I am trying to import the Snake script into my main script with importlib. This is what I have tried:

```
class RunScript:
    gameBar = False
    Title = None
    script = None
    username = None
    display = None
    scriptFolder = None
    #importlib.import_module(name)

    def importScript(args):
        self = args[0]
        self.Title = args[1]
        orgiPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
        if args[2] == 'games':
            self.scriptFolder = str(orgiPath) + '\\data\\Game_%s' % self.Title
        else:
            self.scriptFolder = str(orgiPath) + '\\data\\Program_%s' % self.Title

        path = str(orgiPath) + '\\data\\scripts'
        os.chdir(path)
        print(os.listdir())
        self.script = importlib.import_module('Snake')
```

I have tried the basics of this in a python shell like so:

```
>>> import importlib, os
>>> path = 'C:\\Users\\26099\\Desktop\\DashProject\\data\\scripts'
>>> os.chdir(path)
>>> os.listdir()
['Snake.py', '__init__.py', '__pycache__']
>>> s = importlib.import_module('Snake')
```

importing my script through the Python shell works fine. The problem is when I run the RunScript class I can't import the module and I receive this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Snake'` even though it shows the prints the Snake script when it shows everything in the directory. I am not sure why it works fine in the python shell but my code in my main-program doesn't want to import the file. My main program is to find a script in the scripts folder that matches some sort of user input. So if the user types a name of a script I want to be able to import it

Comment: try to add Snake import in __init__.py

Comment: Which code are you running to import the file? Are you using the function RunScript.importScript?

Comment: I would like to be able to import a script without specifying the name in the __init__file as this file may of been copied there and wouldn't be in the _-init__ file unless specifically added. I am using runScript.importScript

Comment: Make python list al the files in the directory and add them to the init file?

Comment: but wouldnt that import all files then when I only wish to import a specific one

Comment: After creating another file and trying to import it through another file actually saved to my computer I get the same result It wont import at all in a program but works fine in a python shell